Grammar of the incipit of the papal bull "Antiquorum habet fida relatio"
On 22 February 1300, Pope Boniface VIII published the bull Antiquorum habet fida relatio, declaring 1300 the first jubilee year of the Catholic Church, encouraging pilgrimages to Rome and promising a general indulgence to pilgrims. He apparently envisioned having jubilees every 100 years, but the church shortened the cycle soon (in fact, before the first 100 years were over), and since 1475 regular jubilee years have been held every 25 years with only two exceptions. Only a few days ago, Pope Francis opened the Holy Door of St. Peter's Cathedral in Rome to inaugurate the Jubilee Year of 2025.
But how to read this incipit? It turns out that the whole first sentence of the bull reads as follows:

Antiquorum habet fida relatio, quod accedentibus ad honorabilem Basilicam Principis Apostolorum de Urbe, concessae sunt magnae remissiones, et indulgentiae peccatorum.

(Full text here in the footnote.)
It is clear that the general sense is as if it said habemus; some translations I have found online (e.g. on the German Wikipedia entry for the bull) suggest something like “there is a trustworthy account of the ancients.” Now, there is a certain neutral usage of habere, but it generally comes with sic or an adverb, and means something like “to be in a certain state or condition” (e.g. bene habet, it is well; Cic. Mur. 6, 14). But that does not fit here. The only possible object would be fida as acc. pl. – possibly “certain things,” is that really the intended meaning?

Try meaning II.D in Lewsis and Short: https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/LewisShort521/query?report=bibliography&method=proxy&head=habeo&start=0&end=0

Lewis and Short, under habeo II.D tells us that habeo can mean to judge, regard or believe. Indeed the English verb "hold" can have this same metaphorical meaning depending on context and idiom. ("We hold these truths to be self-evident," etc...)
So perhaps the first sentence means, "The faithful account of the ancients (antiquorum fida relatio) holds that (habet quod) to those approaching from the City (accedentibus de Urbe) the honorable basilica of the prince of the apostles (ad honorabilem basilicam principis apostolorum) great remissions of sins have been granted and indulgences (concessae sunt magnae remissiones, et indulgentiae peccatorum)."
